# How do I get the Looper for a new Thread that I just created?

Tags: java, final, android-looper

I'm creating a thread to handle a request.  In the thread I must call `Looper.prepare()` which is require by some other functionality it is using, and then I call `Looper.loop()`.   But when the connection for the request is closed, I get a callback in a different thread.  At that point I need to call `quit()` on the Thread's looper so that loop() will return and the thread will exit.  However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to get that thread's looper.  I don't see any in `Thread` to get the Looper for the thread.  In the `Looper` class I see a way to get the looper for the current class, but I'm not able to pass this information from the inner class of the Thread to the class that creates it:

```
                final Looper l1;
                final Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        l1 = Looper.myLooper(); // ERROR!
                        // initialization goes here
                        Looper.loop();
                        Log.d(logtag,"The request thread is done.");
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
```

and in the callback which immediately follows the above line:

```
webSocket.setClosedCallback(new CompletedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception ex) {
        // other code
        l1.quit();
    }
});
```

I get a compile time error on the line marked above:

```
Cannot assign a value to final variable 'l1'.
```

But I haven't assigned it yet!  If I don't make `Looper` final, then I can't assign to it because it's not final.

Comment: where is it being used afterwards - where is the callback?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I updated the question to show where the callback is

Comment: Sorry I can not see enough of t\your code to understand it, but why would you not call the Looper quit and the end of `run` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because `Looper.loop()` does not return until the loop finishes, which doesn't happen until I call `l1.quit()` from the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like somewhat of a hack, but I created this class (private, in the same file):

```
class LooperHolder {
    Looper l1 = null;
    void setLooper(Looper looper) {
        l1 = looper;
    }
    Looper getLooper() {
        return l1;
    }
}
```

Then I modified my code to go through the looper holder:

```
            final LooperHolder lh = new LooperHolder();
            final Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    lh.setLooper(Looper.myLooper());
                    // initialization goes here
                    Looper.loop();
                    Log.d(logtag,"The request thread is done.");
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

And then in the callback:

```
Looper l1 = lh.getLooper();
if (l1 != null) l1.quit();
```

Comment: You still haven't answered my question.  Where is this `callback` code?  It would also look like you can only have one value of `Looper` - if that is the case why not just have it as a field?

Comment: @ScaryWombat There's a different value each time a request is serviced; there can be multiple threads and each needs its own Looper